# undefined local variable or method `correspondent_loans' for #<CreateCorrespondentLoans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am using rails 4 & ruby 2.0.0.

when I hit rake db:migrate I get the error.  It points to the add_index line having an issue.

```
 ==  CreateCorrespondentLoans: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:correspondent_loans)
-> 0.0036s
-- correspondent_loans()
rake aborted!
 StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

 undefined local variable or method `correspondent_loans' for #<CreateCorrespondentLoans:
```

Here's the code

```
    class CreateCorrespondentLoans < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
 create_table :correspondent_loans do |t|
  t.string :correspondent
  t.date :purchase_date
  t.decimal :loan_amount, precision: 15, scale: 2
  t.string :curr_status
  t.string :instrument_name
  t.string :loan_id, null: false

  t.timestamps
end

add_index correspondent_loans, loan_id, name: "index_correspondent_loans_loan_id", unique: true, using: :btree
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CreateCorrespondentLoans < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :correspondent_loans do |t|
            t.string :correspondent
            t.date :purchase_date
            t.decimal :loan_amount, precision: 15, scale: 2
            t.string :curr_status
            t.string :instrument_name
            t.string :loan_id, null: false
            t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :correspondent_loans, :loan_id, name: "index_correspondent_loans_loan_id", unique: true, using: :btree
    end
end
```

correspondent_loans and load_id should be a symbol.

Comment: That fixed the error but now the error is pointing to loan_id on the same line.  The goal is to make it where it will prevent duplicine loan_id values from being entered.

Comment: same exact error just instead of it saying correspondent_loans() it says loan_id()

Comment: Thanks everything works, googled after your solution and I see how I read the documentation wrong.